# ufotableが書き上げた脚本を、奈須きのこが原作者としてリライトしたのが本稿である。

Tags: meaning

> ufotableが書き上げた脚本を、奈須きのこが原作者としてリライトしたのが本稿である。

My question is according to this sentence what happens to the written text of the film.

I found another sentence from the author himself in [his blog](http://www.typemoon.org/bbb/diary/log/201506.html)

> #25の制作は「ほぼオリジナルなので、まずは原作サイドで書くべし」と始まりました。そしてできあがったきのこによる脚本モドキを前に頭を抱える制作陣。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 「ufotableが書{か}き上{あ}げた脚本{きゃくほん}を、奈須{なす}きのこが原作者{げんさくしゃ}としてリライトしたのが本稿{ほんこう}である。」

Two different works are mentioned here:

1) ufotableが書き上げた脚本 ("the script written by Ufotable")

2) 奈須きのこが原作者としてリライトした**の** ("(what/the thing) Kinoko Nasu has rewritten as the (original) author")  「の」 is a nominalizer.

And please note that the subject of the sentence is 2) and that ***2) is based off of 1)***.

> "This is the manuscript where Kinoko Nasu, as its author, has rewritten based off of the script written by Ufotable."

Comment: I have a few questions. My initial interpretation was that the script Ufotable eventually ended up working with was from a script base, this base being a rewrite of the source material by Kinoko Nasu (who wrote the source material in the first place). Basically my question is I was completely wrong in my translation? There are no different interpretations? Is it because of the を that it is as you say?

Comment: Please answer when you get the time. A mere "yes I'm sure I'm right and you were completely off in your initial understanding of the sentence" would suffice. You don't have to go into detail, it's just to verify I was not right for sure in case the grammar could somehow make my translation plausible (not literal translation but the meaning/spirit behind it)