# #25の制作は「ほぼオリジナルなので、まずは原作サイドで書くべし」と始まりました。そしてできあがったきのこによる脚本モドキを前に頭を抱える制作陣

Tags: meaning

> #25の制作は「ほぼオリジナルなので、まずは原作サイドで書くべし」と始まりました。そしてできあがったきのこによる脚本モドキを前に頭を抱える制作陣。([source](http://www.typemoon.org/bbb/diary/log/201506.html))

My translation:

> I began by thinking that #25's script was "mostly original, so I should write this as a side story to the original [the VN] story." And so I, Kinoko, was at my wits end trying to write something approximating a screenplay.

I'm particularly interested in the reference to the script and how it's supposed to be almost original. Any reference to that script (and where it comes from) I might have neglected is most welcome.

Edit: My translation wasn't very literal. Another approach would be something like:

> The production of episode 25 began with "since it's mostly original content, it should first be written by the original author". And then the production team clutching their heads at the completed so-called script by Kinoko.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Wikipedia:

> [Fate/stay night テレビアニメ第2作](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fate/stay_night#.E3.83.86.E3.83.AC.E3.83.93.E3.82.A2.E3.83.8B.E3.83.A1.E7.AC.AC2.E4.BD.9C)
>   シリーズ構成、脚本はufotableスタッフが担当。奈須は全ての脚本会議に出席、ufotableが制作した脚本に奈須が加筆・修正を加える形で脚本制作監修を行った。
>   <sub>(※奈須 = きのこ)</sub>

So きのこ was both the original author and scenario supervisor of this anime series. With this background, the sentence in question is interpreted as follows:

"I started creating Ep. 25, thinking I should firstly write as if I were just an original author (i.e., only from the original author's perspective)."

It means he intentionally and temporarily forgot about his job as the scenario supervisor of the anime. While he wrote the story of #25, he did not care much about how it would look like as an anime episode. As a result, what he made looked like a long ordinary novel, and it was not directly usable as the screenplay. That's why other staff were at a loss and had to trim much of what he wrote.

Note that this ～サイド does not mean a side story, but something like "～'s standpoint/perspective". 原作 is an original author. ～モドキ is "pseudo ～", "wannabe ～", "mock ～", "-oid", etc.

Comment: Very good answer. Since I take it you watched the anime I'll ask you a question. From your understanding he's the original author of that script (11 page manuscript), his will you could say. How episode 25 turned out to be (there were many changes) was due to the director's work.

Comment: Sorry I haven't watched or read *Fate*. What I wrote is just the summary of his blog article. 『不要な部分、入らない部分はバッサリ没にした……のですが、アニプレさんの粋な計らいで、「このまま奈須さん部分をお蔵入りするのはもったいないので下巻の特典にまとめて入れましょう」というコトになりました。』

Comment: There is no need to watch it for this question anyways. My last question: could you answer this comment with another comment giving a literal translation of the sentence I'm asking about? (this time without any background. You encounter it for the first time and translate it). I'd like that to confirm my suspicions as you seem to know much more japanese than I do. A good literal translation (without flaws) is always very helpful.

Comment: Well, actually I checked Wikipedia just in order to make sure my interpretation was correct. Your second trial at the end of the question seems very good to me except for the 原作サイド part. 原作サイドで here literally means "at the original author's side." It was easy for me to guess that he was talking about his two positions, and that the phrase was the same as 原作者の立場で ("from the original author's standpoint") in this context.

Comment: oh, I see. Then, my very  last question. Can you translate 「ほぼオリジナルなので、まずは原作サイドで書くべし」Since it was the only part you consider to have a mistake, I would like you to write the correct translation (no mistakes).

Comment: ? I mentioned *your* mistake, not *mine*. But anyway, here you go: "Since it's almost original, firstly I should write from the original author's standpoint."

Comment: I know, I meant my mistake =P Note (don't answer this comment and thank you for everything. This is just a clarification if someone encounters this thread): Episodes 1-24 are mainly a copypaste of the author's VN. Here the author writes some things but he mainly supervises. Episode 25 is original,an epilogue. That's why he felt compelled as a true author to write it properly as it is the ending of the series. Here he's no supervisor but author because of it's relevance, which led to lots of changes from the director as it was a very long novel.

Comment: Sorry, a new question has arisen.If you could answer it would be great. The question is the "from the original author's standpoint", to which you gave your interpretation in your answer ("It means he intentionally and temporarily forgot about his job as the scenario supervisor of the anime"). If you read this link that addresses the same situation, does your answer change or you  maintain the same standing. Do you  thing that "from the original author's standpoint" could refer to the previous script? http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/42441/difficulties-understanding-one-sentence

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51743/discussion-between-naruto-and-the-beast).